# Goutte/Guzzle setDefaultOption() method not valid

Tags: symfony, goutte

```
use Goutte\Client;

/**
 * code removed
 */
class  ......... {

  public function xxxxxx() {

    $client = new Client();
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

Gives error "Method setDefaultOption not found in class GuzzleHttp/Client"
Also code completion can not find the method. 
Example is from https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

I am indeed on Guzzle~6 so this code worked:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.example.com',
                              ['curl' => ['CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' => 60]]);
```

Comment: I wrote those docs. Double check what version of Guzzle you are using, those docs could be for Guzzle 4-5 when you are on 6.

Comment: Are you sure $client is not instance of `GuzzleHttp\Client()`?